# Is this the correct way of presenting the formula in code

Tags: math, godot

I am creating a pokemon like game, I am currently trying to add the damage calculations into my game but I am not good at maths or reading formulas, the code I have wrote:

```
func take_damage(move,attacker):
    var modifier : float = rand_range(0.85,1.0)
    var a : float = ((2.0 * attacker.level) / 5) + 2
    var b : float = a * move.power * (attacker.attack() / defence()) + 2.0
    var c : float = b / 50
    var damage = round(c * modifier)
    current_health -= damage
    
    print(damage)
    print(a)
    print(b)
```

and here is a link to where I found pokemons damage calculation with a formula:
https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Damage

What I want to know is, what I have wrote in my code the same as the formula, thanks!

Comment: Looks correct on first inspection. Disregarding non-random modifiers, of course. However, the linked page says it uses "truncated integer division", which would also imply that [`round`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_@gdscript.html#class-gdscript-method-round) is not correct.

Comment: Il remove the round, thanks!

Comment: I believe it should be `int(...)` instead of `round(...)`, also I'm not sure if the other divisions not being integer division are enough to yield different result.

Comment: I have changed it now to be correct, though I have noticed both monsters are doing similar damage I think thats because of modifier that isnt being fully used correctly